# How to pass data in Android cocos2d menuItem selector?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

In Iphone i am able to pass selector id like this way

```
CCMenuItemSprite* item =[CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:normalSprite 
selectedSprite:selectedSprite target:target selector:@selector(LaunchLevel:)];
```

and the selected menuItem tag is obtained by

```
- (void ) LaunchLevel: (id) sender
{
    // Do Something

    CCMenuItemSprite *temp = (CCMenuItemSprite *)sender;
}
```

My question is how to do the similar code in android? Means how to pass the id of the MenuItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this for the moment. If you check the [code source](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/source/browse/trunk/src/org/cocos2d/menus/MenuItem.java) there is nothing for this purpose.
But as cocos2d is open source, nothing prevents you to implement this feature.